# How to apply Newton's method to this system of two equations?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I'm a bit stuck. We're given the following system of equations:
$$3x-2y+1=0$$
$$12x+3y-18=0$$

And they ask us whether Newton's Method converges after only one iteration. It's similar to this question I asked a few days ago [Newton's Method for linearly dependent system of equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598755/newtons-method-for-linearly-dependent-system-of-equations) but here the two equations are not linearly dependent, so the Jacobian is invertible.

The Jacobian is $$\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -2 \\
12 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}
$$ and its determinant is 33.

I'm a bit stuck about what to do next. I googled heavily but could not find an answer to my question.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: @MattiP. In this case, $B= (-1, 18)^T, A^{-1}=1/33 (3 \ \ 3, -12 \ \ 3)^T$. The problem is that I'm not given any initial guess $X_n$. If we have no initial guess, how could we possibly use the formula ?

Comment: (Revised because I made a typo) Newton's method works exactly the same way for multiple variables as it does for a single variable. You have an equation of the form $f(X)=0$, where $X$ is an array of variables; $X=(x,y)^T$. In this case
$$ f(X) = AX-B
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are matrices. The only trick is calculating the "inverse of the derivative". In reality you will use the Jacobian $Jf(X_n)$, and the iteration formula becomes
$$
X_{n+1} = X_n - (Jf(X_n))^{-1} f(X_n)
$$
Notice that this formula is applicable to all multivariable equations of the form $f(X)=0$.

Comment: @MattiP. I have some troubles finding the inverse Jacobian. According to Wikipedia, it's equal to the Jacobian matrix of the Inverse Function. To find the Inverse Function, I can simply invert the matrix $A$, and then find the Jacobian of the system of equation represented by $A$. That would then be my Inverse Jacobian. Then, I can apply Newton's Method. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yeah, I think in this case, since we have a linear system, the Jacobian of $f$ is just $A$. So $Jf(X_N)= A$

Comment: Note that this task is impossible, as it asks to solve a linear system by Newtons method. However the main step of the Newton method is the solution of that same linear system. A vicious circle.

Comment: I tried my numerical Newton's and it converged after one iteration to $$(x, y) = (1, 2)$$

Comment: @Moo What did you take as initial guess $X_n$ ?

Comment: A bunch of different values and it did not matter what it was (of course I didn't try the actual root itself, but it should work there too).

Comment: But when applying the Newton step, when solving the system for the Newton step (with the same system matrix), what method did you use, the Newton method again?

Comment: @Moo : Of course $x_1=x_0-A^{-1}(Ax_0-b)=A^{-1}b$ is independent of the input $x_0$ and gives the solution in one step.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: I hadn't worked that through, but yes, it makes sense. My guess would be that that was the purpose of the exercise, so that would seem like a good answer to post.